# How to resize an ImageView dynamically by dragging from its corners just like a cropping frame on a picture?

Tags: android, imageview

In my android application I am stuck in a problem and nothing seems to work for me.
I have an ImageView on the top of another ImageView inside a relative layout.
Now I need to resize the imageview on top when user touches one of its corners and drags.
Just like a cropping frame we generally see. When we drag any one corner, then the diagonally opposite corner must remain fixed and the resizing must be done across the corner which is being dragged.
What I am doing is setting OnTouchListener and getting new/dragged coordinates on Action.MOVE then I tried to resize using Bitmap's createScaledBitmap. This does resize the image view but not across the corner which is being dragged. I am totally confused .
How I can use the coordinates to draw an Image View just like we do it while drawing a rectangle using Canvas.
Please help.

Answer (score 0):

I wouldn't do this in an ImageView.  I would subclass View and override onTouchEvent and onDraw to handle the input and draw all the various components.  You have to break this down into it's components and manage a number of objects in this view.

You have a Rect that represents the size of the crop area.  This probably defaults to the size of the control.  In onTouchEvent, you need to test for an area around each corner and then keep track of which corner is being dragged to resize your Rect appropriately.

You don't have to call createScaledBitmap each time you draw it, and you probably shouldn't because you are flirting with an OutOfMemoryException at that point (clean up your Bitmaps too slowly and you'll find out the hard way what this is).  Just decode the Bitmap when the control gets created and draw it to the canvas using a destination Rect.

Lots of code to write, but it sounds like a fun project.  There's no easy way to drop in a control like this (if I'm understanding you correctly).  You have to manage the touches, drags, and the destination rectangle inside the custom View.